# Altering filepath after deployment to Heroku to access static files in views.py

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-views, django-urls

My app is for students who provide their ID `CNIC` to get their certificates. A function `download` in `views.py` needs to

1. access an image (which is a blank certificate)
2. modify it by adding `name` and graduation `date` associated with `cnic`
3. save it as pdf
4. make it available for download

All works in development on `localhost` but when deployed to Heroku, the filepath to the image does not exist, which makes sense because the app is not local anymore - it accessible to anyone.

[image]

The question is, how do we find the new path to access `Certificate_0001.jpg` which was initially stored in `certificates\static\certificates`

**Views.py**

```py
def download (request, date, name):
    x = date.split(" ")
    date = f"29 {x[3]} {x[4]}"
    try: 
        image = Image.open("certificates\static\certificates\Certificate_0001.jpg")
    except:
        return HttpResponse ("image did not load")
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 70)
    font_type_2 = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 35)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text(xy=(600, 740), text=name, fill=(0,102,0), font=font_type)
    draw.text (xy=(330, 1230), text=date, fill=(0,102,0), font=font_type_2)
    try:
        image.save(f'certificates\static\certificates\{name}.pdf', "PDF", resolution=100.0)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("pdf did not save")
    try:
        with open(f'certificates\static\certificates\{name}.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline;filename=NFDP-{name}.pdf'
            return response
    except:
        return HttpResponse("pdf did not load")
```

**Settings.py**

```py
import os
import django_heroku
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "certificates"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"), 
    path("download/<str:name>/<str:date>", views.download, name="download")

]
```

**wsgi.py**

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nfdp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Actually, once a Django application is deployed to Heroku, all of the files are placed inside a new directory called `app`. You can also run `heroku run bash` and do `cd app` or go back one folder by `cd ..` and then `cd app`. Then you can see your files in `app_name/static/app_name/my_file.xyz`. Therefore, in order to access your `staticfiles` in `views.py`, you must change the file path so that it runs in production.

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
##BASE_DIR = /app/ in production (heroku) but your project name in development (locally)
path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "certificates/static/certificates/Certificate_0001.jpg")
```